# Failing to import modules within subdirectory

Tags: python, import

I've got a package I'm trying to import certain modules from, but am failing at. The way my directory is structured is:

```
top/
    main_script.py
    middle/
        foo.py
        utils.py
        __init__.py`
```

foo.py imports utils.py just fine whenever I run it, however, if I run main_script.py, foo.py will fail to import utils.py by giving me a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.py'

The way I'm importing foo.py in main_script.py is:
`from middle import foo`

The way I'm importing utils.py into foo.py is:
`import utils`

If I import, say, numpy into foo.py instead of importing utils and run main_script.py it will import and run just fine, however, if foo.py contains utils then running main_script.py will fail.

Any idea on how to fix this without putting my main_script.py into middle/?

Comment: How are you importing foo? Is it a relative import? Might help to share your import snippet as well.

Comment: Edited the question to provide more information

Comment: In foo.py, I've tried editing the import statement to be `import middle.utils as utils` but that gives a `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'middle'`. Similarly, if I try something like`from . import utils` that gives a `ImportError: cannot import name 'utils'`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could share how you are importing in main_script.

Your import should be:

```
from middle import foo
```

Or

```
from middle import foo, utils
```

Comment: I'd also add that, in `foo.py`, the author might be need to specify that `utils` be imported from within `middle` such that this is the import script: `import middle.utils as utils`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**main_script.py**

```
from middle import foo

print(__name__)
```

**foo.py**

```
from middle import utils

print(__name__)
```

**utils.py**

```
print(__name__)
```

To know more about it, just check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)